# C# Error With A progress bar showing progress of a download and ran file from the internet

Tags: c#, progress-bar, runtime-error, webclient

Okay so i am new to programming and i wanted to make a toolstrip with a progress bar that would show the progress of a file fetched from the internet and opened up, here is the code snipplet http://pastebin.com/3EKrFb4K and it doesnt give an error in the code, but when i debug it says this when i try to download and open the file(once it doesnt even do) http://gyazo.com/44634914669d81b1c20d3d26f2dd3ad8 i am wondering if its just something simple or if the code i wrote wont work? it a toolstrip progress bar so do i have to do something special or what? please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are opening the file before it has been downloaded:

WebClient web = new WebClient();
            web.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(direct_exe_from_url), filepath); // this method is asynchronous
            web.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(web_DownloadProgressChanged);
            Process.Start(filepath);  // you open the file while it's still downloading.

You need to execute the process start inside the downloadFileCompleted handler.

This should work:

```
private void startBotToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string directoryPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppData") + "\\Downloaded Files\\";
            string filepath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppData") + "\\Downloaded Files\\" + "Minecraft.exe";
            if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
            }

            string direct_exe_from_url = "http://rs542p2.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=download&fileid=1764003915&filename=Minecraft.exe&cookie=F2CB284BDC9920808D8494CA4EB46F0935AB22D79EC69D6D130C21FB6AD2A0A1EB413347302A46C5FB1A39599DF740D6&directstart=1";

            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            web.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(direct_exe_from_url), filepath);
            web.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(web_DownloadProgressChanged);    
            web.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler (DownloadFileCallback);
        }

        void web_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

         void DownloadFileCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string filepath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppData") + "\\Downloaded Files\\" + "Minecraft.exe";
            Process.Start(filepath);

        }
```

Comment: Thank You! what if i want it to say updating in text infront of the progress bar when it is updating?